# writing in file and binary searching in it

Tags: c++, file, binary-search

I have a file that holds data about books(book's ID, author's ID, book's title and book's price)  and then lets say if I want to delete a book record I search for it via the ID and then delete it.

**This is how I type on the file**

```
int writebook(fstream& stream, book_attributes& BOOKS)
{
    stream.seekp(0, ios::end);
    char buffer[maxBuffersize];
    strcat(buffer, BOOKS.book_id);
    strcat(buffer, BOOKS.author_id);
    strcat(buffer, BOOKS.book_title);
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << BOOKS.book_price;
    string s(ss.str());
    const char *cstr = s.c_str();
    strcat(buffer, cstr);
    short length = strlen(buffer);
    stream.write(buffer, length);
    stream.seekg(0);
    return length;
}
```

Problem is when the data is written on the file there is a three bytes before the ID which result the search not to work properly and I don't really understand why its three  bytes my best guess the first two are the size of record represented in 2 bits because its of type short. Any advice? thank you.

**EDIT**

**This is how I search in case you are asking**

```
bool BinaryBookSearch(fstream & file, book_attributes &rec, char* key)
{
    int low = 0, high = getFileLength(file) / sizeof(rec) - 1;
    int guess;
    while (low <= high)
    {
    guess = (high + low) / 2;
    readBookRecord(file, rec, guess);
    if (Equal(rec.book_id, key))
        return true;
    if (Greater(rec.book_id, key))
        high = guess - 1;
    else
        low = guess + 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(buffer, BOOKS.book_id);` Undefined behavior here. The contents of `buffer` are uninitialized.

Comment: Why are you using a raw char array at all? It would be much easier to accumulate the data in a `string`, or to just write straight to `stream`.

Comment: @melpomene fixed it thanks char buffer[maxBuffersize]={NULL};
and i was trying to do something like
stream.write((char*)&BOOKS, sizeof(BOOKS)); but the file was looking very strange

Comment: Just so you know it is a lot easier to read the data into a container, do what you want to the container, and then overwrite the file with the container when done.

Comment: `char buffer[maxBuffersize]={NULL};` is wrong. `NULL` is a pointer value, not a `char`.

Comment: @melpomene yes but it like gives it no value. I just did that just to give it no value.

Comment: No, it doesn't give it "no value". It happens to set it to `0`, which is the same as `'\0'`. You could have just written `char buffer[maxBuffersize] = { '\0' };`.

Comment: Noted, thanks @melpomene .